# I'm getting an error on my CSS files and JS also. I have no clue what they mean

Tags: html, css

I'm taking a course on CSS3 and HTML5, and I ran into some trouble: my CSS folder isn't located in the correct spot... or something. I have no clue what's going on, but after a few hours of messing around, I went into the inspect element tool, and noticed some files aren't loading, so that's why my CSS isn't working! I attached an image, can you tell me what it means?

Also, where should my CSS file be? I'm using bootstrap and sublime text.

Thanks in advance.

Well, nvm on that image. It says I need 10 credits...

It says  in inspect element:

Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: No image there, you have no sufficient reputation to attach an image. Post your directory structure and markup from where you are trying to load your js and css files.

Comment: Second
  dist
   css (my css folder is located in here)
   fonts
   js
  title.html(the website I'm making.)

Comment: That didn't come out the way I planned... I'm new to this.

Comment: post some of your code

Answer (score 0):

CSS files can be called from a path relative to the document calling them. For instance, given you have a folder directory that looks like this:

```
/(your root directory)
-css
 -bootstrap
  app.css
-img
-js
index.html
-pages
 pageone.html
```

...your css link in your index should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/app.css" />
```

whereas the link for pageone.html would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap/app.css" />
```

the `../` tells the server to look in a directory directly above the calling file for the path described in the link

With Bootstrap, are you using straight CSS, LESS, or SCSS? If you're using a pre-compiler, check your pre-compiler's settings file to ensure your compiled css files end up in the proper directory.

Answer (score 0):

In sublime text for getting directory path please install a package called Auto File Name if you have a package control already installed in your sublime if not, the google package control and install in your sublime editor , auto file name lets you go well in your directory path and call your files.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem before. the external stylesheets is not recongnized !!

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

If your HTML is in the root and your CSS folder is also in the root then your links are incorrect. You shouldn't have a slash / in front of the file name.

try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

[see this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/external-stylesheets-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

when you build your react project the links of the file will look like this:     `<link href="/static/css/main.5b4fdda8.css" rel="stylesheet">`
there is an extra / in the href before the static, it will also be in your link you just have to remove it like this:

```html
<link href="static/css/main.5b4fdda8.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and now you are ready to go.

You can see this article for details:

```
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/external-stylesheets-not-found
```